# How can I create a dataset with 3 new columns (each one from a different dataset) and rename them?

Tags: r

I know this is an easy question but I´m really struggling and trying to be efficent with my code.
I have 3 different datasets:

```
    head(Porto_2014)
    + select(points_acc)     
          points_acc
    1          3
    2          6
    3          9
    4         10
    5         11
    6         12

    head(Porto_2015) %>%
    + select(points_acc)
      points_acc
    1          3
    2          4
    3          7
    4         10
    5         13
    6         14

head(Porto_2016) %>%
+ select(points_acc)
  points_acc
1          3
2          6
3          6
4          9
5         10
6         13
```

I want to create a new dataframe `points_by_season` with 3 columns named `Season_X` being `X` the year of the season.
I must recall that I want to be super eficient with lines used to code.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cbind`

In case Porto_2014, Porto_2015 and Porto_2016 have the same number of rows:

```
points_by_season <- cbind(Season_2014=Porto_2014$points_acc
 , Season_2015=Porto_2015$points_acc
 , Season_2016=Porto_2016$points_acc)
```

if they have not the same number of rows:

```
tt <- seq_len(max(nrow(Porto_2014), nrow(Porto_2015), nrow(Porto_2016)))
points_by_season <- cbind(Season_2014=Porto_2014$points_acc[tt]
 , Season_2015=Porto_2015$points_acc[tt]
 , Season_2016=Porto_2016$points_acc[tt])
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to load it into a `list` by getting the values of the objects (with `mget`), loop over the list (`imap`),  `select` the column while renaming it replacing 'Porto' with 'Season' from the names of the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap_dfc(mget(str_c("Porto_", 2014:2016)), ~ .x %>%
            select(!!str_replace(.y, "Porto", "Season") := points_acc)) 
#   Season_2014 Season_2015 Season_2016
#1           3           3           3
#2           6           4           6
#3           9           7           6
#4          10          10           9
#5          11          13          10
#6          12          14          13
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(mget(paste0("Porto_", 2014:2016)),
           `[`, 'points_acc')), paste0("Season_", 2014:2016))
```

#### data

```
Porto_2014 <- structure(list(points_acc = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
Porto_2015 <- structure(list(points_acc = c(3L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
Porto_2016 <- structure(list(points_acc = c(3L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: @JoãoMachado  Thanks, I corrected that.  Can you check the `packageVersion("dplyr")`